# How is the necromancer badge awarded?

Tags: support, badges, notifications, necromancer-badge

I earned the necromancer badge 1 hour ago. I wasn't online 1 hour ago. I earned it for [a post which was last edited on the 10th of September, last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68953). What's going on here?

Comment: Necromancers are sorcerers using black magic to animate dead bodies. So it is only logically the badge is awarded when you are not looking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Badges are awarded in a batch process. The batch process ran 1 hour ago.

Moreover, the necromancer badge has a vote requirement; you need 5 upvotes on the post before it is eligible for the badge, and you don't need to be online to receive votes either. :-)